# Plot multiple functions in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I tried to multiple plot in WolframAlpha using this command from the Forum:

```
plot {1<=x<=2 1<y<3} and plot {x=4 1<y<3} and plot {1<=x<=2 y=4} and plot {x=4 y=4} and plot {1<=x<=2 5<=y<=6} and plot {x=4 5<=y<=6}
```

But it's not working. Where is my mistake?